In how many fragments a water drop will split into if falls on a smooth surface from a height h?
I am analysing a phenomena in which an acid drop(say the acid is aqua regia) of 5-6 mm size drops on a smooth surface from a height of say 6 inches. As it hits surface it gets fragmented and bounces off in different direction.
I want to know in how many drops it will break into and how much distant the drops will fall after collision?
I want to keep distant from the area of experiment as the flying droplets might injure me or my clothes.
I know this a difficult problem but any solution will be of great help.

Tis has no simple solution it is very random. Why not do some experiments with harmless water drops, or just keep far away?

The part about how many droplets it will split into is virtually impossible to determine experimentally, but I would argue here’s a decent question that can be answered with classical mechanics: what’s the maximum distance a droplet with $X%$ of the drop’s original mass could travel when dropped from a particular height? This would be constrained by the kinetic energy of the droplet which limits its velocity and thus how far it can travel.

@trula Are you saying if I repeat the same experiment again under same conditions I will get results dictated by pure chance ?

@controlgroup practically I dont know the X % you are talking about.

That’s the issue you’re gonna have - you can’t really predict what you’re trying to predict in an efficient way. You could do some experimentation with slow-mo video and do an experiment to find a good approximation, though. Personally I don’t know about any such experiments and thus can’t directly answer what $X$ is but it seems easy enough to find out.

A first-order estimate can be worked out, as follows.
Calculate the potential energy of the droplet before it falls. Assume that upon impact, all the potential energy is losslessly converted into surface energy in the form of a series of droplets of summed surface area A, knowing the surface tension of the acid.
